# Nested for loop to search 2 lists

Tags: python, search, string-matching, nested-loops, nested-lists

Using: Python 2.4

Currently, I have a nested for loop that iterates over 2 lists and makes a match based on two elements that exists on both lists.  Once a match has been found, it the element from the r120Final list and puts in a new list called "r120Delta":

```
for r120item in r120Final:
    for spectraItem in spectraFinal:
    if(str(spectraItem[0]) == r120item[2].strip()) and (str(spectraItem[25]) == r120item[10]):
        r120Delta.append(r120item)
        break
```

The problem is that this is SO SLOW and the lists aren't that deep.  The R120 is about 64,000 lines and the Spectra is about 150,000 lines.

The r120Final list is a nested array and it looks like so:

```
r120Final[0] = [['xxx','xxx','12345','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','234567']]
...
r120Final[n] = [['xxx','xxx','99999','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','678901']]
```

The spectraFinal list is essentially the same, a nested array and it looks like so:

```
spectraFinal[0] = [['12345','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','234567']]
...
spectraFinal[0] = [['99999','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx','678901']]
```

Finally, the reason for the "r120Delta" is so that way I can then do a list differential between r120Final and r120Delta and retrieve r120 data elements that were NOT matched.  This is the function I defined for this very task, and again, slow:

```
def listDiff( diffList, completeList ):
    returnList = []
        for completeItem in completeList:
            if not completeItem  in diffList:
                returnList.append(completeItem)
    return returnList
```

Basically, I'm knowledgeable in Python but by no means an expert.  I'm looking for some experts to show me how to speed this up.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are the r120Final and spectralFinal are two different files where each list item is a line in the file? If so i can show you how to do this real fast with the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
spectra_set = set((str(spectraItem[0]), str(spectraItem[25])) for spectraItem in spectraFinal)

returnList = []
for r120item in r120Final:
    if (r120item[2].strip(), r120item[10]) not in spectra_set:
       returnList.append(r120item)
```

This will add all items that didn't match to the `returnList`.

You can do it in one line (if you really want) as

```
returnList = [r120item for r120item in r120Final 
                 if (r120item[2].strip(), r120item[10]) not in 
                     set((str(spectraItem[0]), str(spectraItem[25])) 
                         for spectraItem in spectraFinal)]
```

If you need the full `spectraItem`:

```
spectra_dict = dict(((str(spectraItem[0]), str(spectraItem[25])), spectraItem) for spectraItem in spectraFinal)
returnList = []
for r120item in r120Final:
    key = (r120item[2].strip(), r120item[10])
    if key not in spectra_dict:
        returnList.append(r120item)
    else:
        return_item = some_function_of(r120item, spectra_dict[key])
        returnList.append(return_item)
```

Comment: You might also want to look into Numpy (http://numpy.scipy.org/), which has some great support for slicing-and-dicing multidimensional arrays.

Comment: Wow, that helped out... A LOT!

Comment: Now, how would I use that to match elements from both lists and merge them?  Say, once a match is found, I want to merge the r120Final data element and some select spectraFinal elements together, such as spectraFinal[8], spectraFinal[5], spectraFinal[2], and spectraFinal[23]?

Comment: Edited to show how you can get near the same speed and still access the full `spectraItem`, which I assume is what you meant.

Comment: That was absolutely helpful, but could you point me if, say, I wanted SELECT spectraItems like I mentioned above?  That would hit it on the head.  :)